# Vaex datetime error unknown variables or column

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, time, vaex

I got a `vaex.dataframe.DataFrame` called `df` holding a time column called `timestamp` of type string. I convert the column to datetime as follows

```py
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype as is_datetime

if not is_datetime(df['timestamp']):
    df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(np.datetime64)
```

Then I just want to select rows of `df` where the `timestamp` is in a specific range. Lets say

```py
sliced_df = df[(df['timestamp'] > np.datetime64("2022-01-01"))]
```

I am doing that in Sagemaker and it throws a huge error mainly saying the following error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 106, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 166, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Unknown variables or column: %r" % (variable,))
KeyError: "Unknown variables or column: 'datetime64(__timestamp)'"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/expression.py", line 1327, in _apply
    scalar_result = self.f(*[fix_type(k[i]) for k in args], **{key: value[i] for key, value in kwargs.items()})
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "nan" at position 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 265, in __getitem__
    values = self.evaluate(expression)  # , out=self.buffers[variable])
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 188, in evaluate
    result = eval(expression, expression_namespace, self)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/arrow/numpy_dispatch.py", line 136, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/expression.py", line 1312, in __call__
    return vaex.multiprocessing.apply(self._apply, args, kwargs, self.multiprocessing)
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/multiprocessing.py", line 32, in apply
    result = _get_pool().apply(f, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 261, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/custom_python/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "nan" at position 0
ERROR:MainThread:vaex.scopes:error in evaluating: 'timestamp'
"""
```

The `df` holds values similar to these under the column `timestamp`

```
<pyarrow.lib.StringArray object at 0x7f569e5f54b0>
[
  "2021-12-19 06:01:10.789",
  "2021-12-20 07:02:11.89",
  "2022-01-01 08:02:12.678",
  "2022-01-02 09:03:13.567",
  "2022-01-03 10:04:14.456"
]
```

The time stamps look fine to me. I compared with previous data where the comparison worked and nothing seems to be different. I have no clue why this now is not working anymore. I am trying to wrap my head around it for days now but really can't find why its throwing that error.

When I check for

```py
df[df.timestamp.isna()]
```

it returns nothing. So I don't understand why it found `nan` in the first position as stated in the error message above.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are comparing arrow timestamps to numpy timestamps. You need to chose one framework and work with that.

This issues on vaex's github discusses what you are facing a bit, so it might clear things up more:
https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/1704